# NullPointerException while adding view in a fragment dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to dynamically add a TableLayout into a LinearLayout inside a fragment.

Code below:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment, container, false);
        dash_board = (LinearLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.layout.dashboard_fragment);
        table = new TableLayout(getActivity());
        TableRow tr_header = new TableRow(getActivity());
        TextView Name = new TextView(getActivity());

        Name.setText("Name");
        LayoutParams Name_params =  new LayoutParams();
        Name_params.width= 100;

        Name.setLayoutParams(Name_params);
        Name.setPadding(2, 0, 2, 2);

        tr_header.addView(Name);

        TextView Points = new TextView(getActivity());

        Points.setText("Points");
        LayoutParams point_params =  new LayoutParams();
        point_params.width= 100;

        Points.setLayoutParams(point_params);
        Points.setPadding(2, 0, 2, 2);

        tr_header.addView(Points);

        table.addView(tr_header);

        dash_board.addView(table);

        return rootview;
    }
```

But while adding table to the dash board layout (dash_board.addView(table);) I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment, container, false);
    dash_board = (LinearLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.layout.dashboard_fragment);
```

it should be

```
LinearLayout dash_board = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment,              container, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no dashboard_fragment as a ViewGroup in rootView because the rootView is exacly the dashboard_fragment as a ViewGroup.So these two lines of code are the cause of exception:

> View rootview =
> inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment,container, false);
>
> dash_board =
> (LinearLayout)rootview.findViewById(R.layout.dashboard_fragment);

Actually the logic will be correct if you do like this:

> View rootview =
> inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment,container, false);
>
> dash_board =
> (LinearLayout) rootView;

And this is the simplest form for this process:

> dash_board
> =(LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment,container, false);